# Dynamic LIKE clause or something like LIKE IN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-like

I have requirement like below:

There are two tables i)**TB_VALUES** and ii)**TB_KEYWORDS**.

Here are some sample data for

**TB_VALUES**:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Description`**</kbd>                     
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Oracle is better than SQL Server`</kbd>
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Python is good`</kbd>                  
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Why should we use oracle`</kbd>        
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`pl/sql guidelines`</kbd>               
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`python tutorial`</kbd>

**TB_KEYWORDS**:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Keywords`**</kbd>   
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Oracle`</kbd>     
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`SQL`</kbd>        
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`SQL`</kbd>

We have to now find the data from TB_VALUES , the Description of those data should contain the keyword.
That means for 00001 the description should contain "**SQL**" or "**Oracle**" (**case** **insensitive**) and for 00002 the description should contain "**SQL**"(**case** **insensitive**) . Our output should be like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Description`**</kbd>                     
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Oracle is better than SQL Server`</kbd>
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Why should we use oracle`</kbd>        
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`pl/sql guidelines`</kbd>

For that we have to write something like this:

```
SELECT V.ID,V.DESCRIPTION FROM TB_VALUES V JOIN TB_KEYWORDS K ON V.ID = K.ID
WHERE UPPER(V.DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%SQL%' OR UPPER(V.DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%ORACLE%' AND V.ID = 00001     
UNION ALL
SELECT V.ID,V.DESCRIPTION FROM TB_VALUES V JOIN TB_KEYWORDS K ON V.ID = K.ID
WHERE UPPER(V.DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%SQL%' AND V.ID = 00002
```

But I want to do it dynamically.

> I can achieve this in PL/SQL but I want output as a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join + `INSTR` might help.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  tb_values (id, description) as
  4    (select 1, 'oracle is better than SQL server' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'python is Good'                   from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'Why should we use Oracle'         from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'pl/sql guidelines'                from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'python tutorial'                  from dual
  9    ),
 10  tb_keywords (id, keywords) as
 11    (select 1, 'Oracle' from dual union all
 12     select 1, 'SQL'    from dual union all
 13     select 2, 'SQL'    from dual
 14    )
 15  -- query you need
 16  select distinct
 17    k.id,
 18    v.description
 19  from tb_keywords k join tb_values v on v.id = k.id
 20    and instr(lower(v.description), lower(k.keywords)) > 0
 21  order by k.id, v.description;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------
         1 oracle is better than SQL server
         1 Why should we use Oracle
         2 pl/sql guidelines

SQL>
```

---

If it were a view (as you mentioned), then - based on those tables - it might look like this:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_key as
  2  select distinct
  3    k.id,
  4    k.keywords,
  5    v.description
  6  from tb_keywords k join tb_values v on v.id = k.id
  7    and instr(lower(v.description), lower(k.keywords)) > 0;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from v_key
  2  where lower(keywords) = 'sql';

        ID KEYWOR DESCRIPTION
---------- ------ --------------------------------
         1 SQL    oracle is better than SQL server
         2 SQL    pl/sql guidelines

SQL>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Why didn't  INNER JOIN come to my mind ?

Comment: You're welcome. Why? Well, perhaps it would have, if you overslept the night and think it over tomorrow :)